# nodejs - Sequelize destroy not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am running into issues while trying to delete a row from a table. In general, the row is not being deleted even though the console logs show that Sequelize is executing a DELETE query.

My code:

```
await UserItem.destroy({
  where: {
    userSteamId,
    assetId
  }
});
```

And the console log shows:

```
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `user_item` WHERE `user_steam_id` = '76561198056233432' AND `asset_id` = '1881811583708444794'
```

If I copy and paste the query and execute it in the MySQL terminal it works like a charm. Any ideas/suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `.catch` callback to your call so you can see if Sequelize is throwing an exception?

Comment: @wolfson I have this piece of code wrapped in a try/catch block, and I'm logging the caught error and doing error handling in the catch block. Nothing appears there at all.

Comment: Does the below answer works ?

Comment: TypeError: User.destory is not a function. "version": "5.8.5" of `sequelize`

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue too, any solution?

Comment: Maybe you need to commit the transaction?